# How to prove 2x2 rotation matrix is a manifold

Tags: matrices, manifolds

How can I prove that this matrix is a manifold?

$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(a) & -\sin(a) \\
\sin(a) & \cos(a)
\end{pmatrix}$

Thanks!

Comment: You just proved half of it. Compute the derivative of that matrix to prove the other half.

Comment: By the given matrix, do you mean the set $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos a&-\sin a\\ \sin a&\cos a\end{pmatrix} : a \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$, and by "is a manifold" do you mean "has a natural manifold structure"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what a manifold is?  Does a matrix fit the description?

Comment: I think we should call in a philosopher. I mean, how do we know that two objects we are describing are actually different? Maybe that matrix really is a 4-sphere.

Comment: @MattSamuel I believe Robert's point is that OP probably means to indicate the set of all such matrices, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$, is a manifold with some natural structure, and not that the particular matrix is literally a manifold.

Comment: @Travis I think the point is that it's not possible to actually mean that and still write what the OP wrote.

Comment: Is than an answer? Seems like a snark comment. Usually, if you are seeking clarification, that calls for a comment.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that as the question is stated it's a fine answer. He didn't need clarification, he is answering what the OP is asking.

Comment: If you think that is what the OP meant to ask, sure. But any sensible person with experience knows what the OP probably meant, and yes, this answer is not only snarky, it is also unhelpful. @MattSamuel

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think a sensible person with experience would know that the OP doesn't know what the OP is asking, and would answer the clear question given in perfect English sentences. Anything else I say about this would border on rudeness, so I'm done.

Comment: Except Robert didn't answer the question as stated. He made no effort to explicate. @MattSamuel